# CSS - how to set up a huge image to the size of window of browser?

Tags: html, css, image, background, position

I have a huge image (3000px on 2000px) and I would like to set this image as a background of website and adjust proportions of the image to the window. So far I am doing this:

```
body {
    background: url('image.jpg') !important;
    background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
    background-attachment: fixed !important;
    background-position: center !important;
}
```

The image is set up on the background, but it's not completely visible - just the "center" of the image, not the whole image.

Is there any way to do it with using CSS?

Comment: use background-size: 100%;

Answer (score 1):

I think you want this:

```
* {
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
border: 0px groove;
}
body {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background-image: url(picture);
background-size: 100%;
}
```

Comment: When ur question is answered can you Click the Check box.

Answer (score 0):

Use `background-size:100%;`

Also, **[Check this link](http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/)** for further reference.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following in your css

```
html
{
height:100%;
width:100%;
}

body{
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
height:100%;
width:100%;
background-image: url(picture);
}
```

to remove any margins or padding and set the Body to full

to do it with html page only

```
<html>
<body background="bgimage.jpg" style="height:100%; width:100%;">
<h1>Hello world!</h1>

</body>
</html>
```

See the W3schools example below 
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_body_background